# Why do I keep getting error message "a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token" in C++?

Tags: c++

For a project I have to create a simple, menu-driven conversion software package that the user enters a number and converts among other things, meters to feet, feet to meters, etc. I have to use a function for each conversion. I have started with the meters to feet function. But when I  compile it I get the error message "a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token." How do I fix this? I am also a beginner.

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double meters_infeet(double meters){
double totalmetersinfeet = (meters * 3.280839895);
return totalmetersinfeet;
}
double feet_inmeters(double feet){
 double totalfeetinmeters = (feet / 3.280839895);
return totalfeetinmeters;
}   
 double area_infeet(double length_inmeters, double width_inmeters){
 double totalareainfeet = (length_inmeters * 3.280839895) 
return totalareainfeet;
 }
 double area_inmeters(double length_infeet, double width_infeet){
 double totalareainmeters = (length_infeet / 3.280839895) 
return totalareainmeters;
 }



int main()
 {
 int choice;
 double meters;
 double feet;
 double length_inmeters;
 double width_inmeters;
 double length_infeet;
 double  width_infeet;

 do{

 cout << "English-Metric Junior" << endl;
 cout << "1)Convert from meters to feet" << endl;
 cout << "2) Convert from feet to meters" << endl;
 cout << "3) Compute the area of a rectangle in square feet given width
 cout << "4) Compute the area of a rectangle in  meters given the length
 cout << "5) Quit the Program" << endl;
 cout << "Please enter a number (1-5)" << endl;
 cin >> choice;
 }while(choice > 5);



 switch (choice)
{
case 1:
cout << "Enter Meters" << endl;
cin >> meters;
cout << meters_infeet(meters)<< "Feet " << endl;
break;
case 2:
cout << "Enter Feet" << endl;
cin >> feet;
cout << feet_inmeters(feet)<< "Meters " << endl;
break;
case 3:
cout << "Enter length in meters" << endl;
cin >> length_inmeters;
cout << "Enter width in meters" << endl;
 cin >> width_inmeters;
cout << area_infeet( length_inmeters, width_inmeters) << endl;
break;
case 4:
cout << "Enter length in feet" << endl;
cin >> length_infeet;
cout << "Enter width in feet" << endl;
cin >> width_infeet;
cout << area_inmeters(length_infeet, width_infeet)<< endl;
break;
```

Comment: You should add the line number where you have your error. Your mistake is simple: note that your `switch` is outside the main function, you should move the first `}` to the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you defined function `main` within function `meters_infeet`

```
double meters_infeet(double meters)
{
    double totalmetersinfeet = meters * 3.280839895;
    return totalmetersinfeet;


   int main()
```

You missed the closing brace of function.`meters_infeet`

It seems that this closing brace

```
  cin >> choice;
 }
```

is the closing brace that has to be after the return statement of `meters_infeet` and before `main`.

It gets lost in the program.:)

And in this code snippet

```
 switch (choice)
{
case 1:
cout << "Enter Meters" << endl;
cin >> meters;
double meters_infeet(double meters);
break;
}
```

statement

```
double meters_infeet(double meters);
```

is a function declaration.
I think you mean something like

```
double feets = meters_infeet( meters );
```

**EDIT:** It is a bad idea to change the code in the question when the original question before updating was already answered. Because in this case readers will not see a relation between the question and the answers.

First of all these functions do not make sense

```
 double area_infeet(double length_inmeters, double width_inmeters){
 double totalareainfeet = (length_inmeters * 3.280839895) 
return totalareainfeet;
 }
 double area_inmeters(double length_infeet, double width_infeet){
 double totalareainmeters = (length_infeet / 3.280839895) 
return totalareainmeters;
 }
```

Their second parameters are not used.

The switch statement should be inside the do-while statement

```
do {
 cout << "English-Metric Junior" << endl;
 cout << "1)Convert from meters to feet" << endl;
 cout << "2) Convert from feet to meters" << endl;
 cout << "3) Compute the area of a rectangle in square feet given width
 cout << "4) Compute the area of a rectangle in  meters given the length
 cout << "5) Quit the Program" << endl;
 cout << "Please enter a number (1-5)" << endl;
 cin >> choice;

 switch (choice)
 {
   //...
 }

} while( choice != 5);
```

Comment: ok thanks I added the brace. But when I run the code after the user enters number of meters it ends. How do I get it to run the function and then output the total for meters in feet?

Comment: @dallascowboys See my updated post. And why are you named dallascowboys instead of dallascowboy?:)

Comment: I have updated my code. I am finished but my do while loop is not working? I want the user to be able to pick from the menu repeatedly options 1-4 and then press 5 to end the program.